# SQL Recur every x weekday every x weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, recurrence

I'm trying to write a sql query which depending on what the user selects will recur every x day every x weeks.
So the user will select that they want the job to recur on tuesdays every 2 weeks
the values that are supplied are

```
declare @StartDate datetime -- when the job first recurs
declare @recurrenceValue1 int -- amount of weeks
declare @recurrenceValue2 int -- day of week (mon-sun)
declare @NextOcurrance datetime -- when the job will recur
```

I know how to set it for the amount of weeks:

```
SET @NextOccurance = (Convert(char(12),@StartDate + (@RecurrenceValue1),106))
```

But I'm not sure how to make it roll on to the day of the week so if the @startDate is today and it should recur every 2 weeks on a tuesday it will see that 2 weeks today is wednesday so will loop until it know that the day is tuesday and that will be the @NextRecurrance date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi yea it is - i m using sqlserver2008

Comment: Do you want the Tuesday _before_ the 'Wednesday + 2 weeks', or the Tuesday _after_ the 'Wednesday + 2 weeks'?  And does that change if somebody has the first 'Recur' date as Tuesday, but the day-of-week is supposed to be Wednesday?  Are you trying to write a function, or store data for a scheduling service (and if so, what is your schema, and can you change it)?

Comment: @X-Zero if the user choses a start date of today the job will run today then a scheduled task will run the procedure above. The NextOccurance date then needs to be set for the Tuesday after the 2 weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to add a number of weeks to a date is to use ([MSDN DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx))

```
DATEADD(wk, @StartDate, @recurrenceValue1)
```

To find out which day of the week the date you are looking at belongs, you can use ([MSDN DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx))

```
DATEPART(dw, @StartDate)
```

This function uses DATEFIRST to determine which day of the week is the first one (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 --Where 1 = Monday and 7 = Sunday
```

So for your problem (DATEFIRST being set to 1 = Monday)..

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

declare @StartDate datetime -- when the job first recurs
declare @recurrenceValue1 int -- amount of weeks
declare @recurrenceValue2 int -- day of week (mon-sun)
declare @NextOcurrance datetime -- when the job will recur


SET @StartDate = '2011-12-16' -- This is a Friday
SET @recurrenceValue1 = 2 -- In 2 weeks
SET @recurrenceValue2 = 2 -- On Tuesday
SET @NextOcurrance = DATEADD(wk, @recurrenceValue1, @StartDate) -- Add our 2 weeks
/* Check if our incrementation falls on the correct day - Adjust if needed */
IF (DATEPART(dw, @NextOcurrance) != @recurrenceValue2) BEGIN
    DECLARE @weekDay int = DATEPART(dw, @NextOcurrance)
    SET @NextOcurrance = DATEADD(dd, ((7 - @weekDay) + @recurrenceValue2), @NextOcurrance) -- Add to @NextOcurrance the number of days missing to be on the requested day of week
END
```

The logic for the number of days to add is as follow:
We have 7 days in a week, how many days does it take to reach the end of this week. Add this number of days to the @recurrenceValue2 (day of week we are looking for).

PS: I can't post more than 2 HyperLinks because of my reputation. This is why the DATEFIRST URL is in plain text.

---

Here's some code to allow certain specific date to be handled differently. Though this code is good only for unique dates. If ones needs to skip an entire week for instance, using this code will require to add values for each day of this week to skip. For ranges other than unique days, this code should be modified to handle date ranges or specific weeks and/or day of week.

```
CREATE TABLE OccurenceExclusions (
    ExclusionDate DATE not null,
    NumberOfDaysToAdd int not null

    PRIMARY KEY (ExclusionDate)
)

INSERT OccurenceExclusions VALUES ('2012-01-01', 7)

SET @NextOcurrance = DATEADD(dd, COALESCE((SELECT NumberOfDaysToAdd
                           FROM OccurrenceExclusions
                           WHERE ExclusionDate = @NextOcurrance), 0), @NextOcurrance)
```

Comment: + 1 - As much as I think calendar files are a good idea, and incredibly useful, this is a nice, simple solution.  Of course, this precludes excluding certain days (if the Tuesday is a holiday), but works perfectly well otherwise.

Comment: The good thing about this code is that it's dynamic and that since it uses the DATEADD function, it automatically deals with leap years, 30 vs 31 month days, etc. It could be combined with a 'exclusion' table where the information stored are the Year, Month, Week number, and Day of week the occurrence should occur. I will add some code to deal with that case.

Comment: If holidays are an issue, he should just use a calendar table, like for @Stuart's answer.  I wouldn't mix the two versions.

Comment: that looks like what i m looking for thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be to use a calendar table. http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

You could then query it like so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @NextOccurance = Date
FROM CalendarTable
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(week, @recurranceValue1, @StartDate)
AND DateName = @recurranceValue2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the principles the @DanielM set out i changed it to fit my query see below:

```
    BEGIN
    SET DATEFIRST 1 --Where 1 = Monday and 7 = Sunday 
    declare @StartDate datetime -- when the job first recurs   
    declare @recurrenceValue1 int -- amount of weeks   
    declare @recurrenceValue2 int -- day of week (mon-sun)   
    declare @NextOcurrance datetime -- when the job will recur   
                        -- sets @nextoccurence to next date after x amount of weeks
 SET @NextOccurance = DATEADD(wk, @recurrenceValue1, @StartDate) -- Add on weeks /* Check if our incrementation falls on the correct day - Adjust if needed */ 
                        IF (DATEPART(dw, @NextOccurance) != @recurrenceValue2) 
                        BEGIN  
                        DECLARE @Weekday int = DATEPART(dw, @NextOccurance)      
                        SET @NextOccurance = DATEADD(dd, (@RecurrenceValue2 - @Weekday), @NextOccurance) -- Add to @NextOcurrance the number of days missing to be on the requested day of week
                        END
                    END
```